# USB Port recognition fails after some seconds

Tags: usb, devices

There are tons of posts around this topic but mine is somehow unique I found.

---

**PROBLEM**

Device 1:
When plugging in any USB storage device like external hard drive, USB stick, card reader or phone, the device is not detected in any way (Disk program, fdisk, lshw, adb (for phone), lsusb). Others like web cam, mouse, keyboard are detected right away without problems or delay.
However I noticed that when plugging in a external 2.5 inch hard drive, its light flashes on for a couple of seconds before going off again. Same happens to status LED of any USB stick or card reader. They all seem to loose power connection after some seconds.

Device 2: Detects all of my devices.

---

**SPECS**

Device 1: USB ports (2.0 and 3.0) on GIGABYTE GA-970A-DS3P main board

Device 2: USB ports (3.0) Lenovo ThinkPad Carbon-X 3rd gen.

both machines run Ubuntu 18.04, I've testes all testing devices on all ports.

---

Any clues on where to start digging for a solution?

Comment: What are you comparing Ubuntu 18.04 to? Do you have both 20.04 and 18.04 on the same machine?

Comment: No both machines run 18.04. This text describes the problems that I'm facing with my PC. I just added below, that my laptop doesn't have any of these.

Comment: So this is two distinct computers running the same OS and using the same USB devices? If this is the case, please update your question to explain this and include the brand and model of the machines, as some have different USB subsystems that can lead to issues.

Comment: No Sir, two machines with a different set of USB ports. I've updated the description. Hope it's clear now.